# Cygwin+conan+cmake: how to force use of Ninja?

Tags: cmake, cygwin, conan

I installed Cygwin with packages for `python`, `cmake` and `Ninja`.
Then I installed Conan (as recommended - with `pip`).
Now when I try Conan with minimal `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
bzip2/1.0.8
```

It fails with

> CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles

(full log pasted below).

I have the reason for avoiding MinGW, so the question is: how to force conan+cmake to use ninja instead of "MinGW Makefiles"??

Tried to set as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548337/how-to-choose-ninja-as-cmake-generator-with-conan), no luck.

> $ conan install -pr clang . --build=bzip2 Configuration: [settings]
> arch=x86_64 arch_build=x86_64 build_type=Release compiler=clang
> compiler.cppstd=17 compiler.libcxx=libc++ compiler.version=14
> os=Windows os_build=Windows [options] [build_requires] [env]
> CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja bzip2/1.0.8: Forced build from source
> conanfile.txt: Installing package Requirements
> bzip2/1.0.8 from 'conancenter' - Cache
> cmake/3.24.0 from 'conancenter' - Cache Packages
> bzip2/1.0.8:fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0 - Build
> cmake/3.24.0:0a420ff5c47119e668867cdb51baff0eca1fdb68 - Cache
>
> Installing (downloading, building) binaries... bzip2/1.0.8: WARN:
> Build folder is dirty, removing it:
> /home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0
> bzip2/1.0.8: Copying sources to build folder bzip2/1.0.8: Building
> your package in
> /home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0
> bzip2/1.0.8: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt bzip2/1.0.8:
> Calling generate() bzip2/1.0.8: WARN: Using the new toolchains and
> generators without specifying a build profile (e.g: -pr:b=default) is
> discouraged and might cause failures and unexpected behavior
> bzip2/1.0.8: Aggregating env generators bzip2/1.0.8: Calling build()
> bzip2/1.0.8: CMake command: cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake"
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/package/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0"
> -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0/src/.."
> CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles
>
> Generators
>
> - Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.   Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.   Ninja
>   Multi-Config           = Generates build-.ninja files.
>   CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
>   CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
>   CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
>   CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
>   Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project
>   files.   Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0
>   project files.   Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project
>   files.   Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
>   Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
>   Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
>   = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
>
> bzip2/1.0.8: bzip2/1.0.8: ERROR: Package
> 'fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0' build failed bzip2/1.0.8:
> WARN: Build folder
> /home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0/build/Release ERROR: bzip2/1.0.8: Error in build() method, line 69
> cmake.configure(build_script_folder=os.path.join(self.source_folder,
> os.pardir))   ConanException: Error 1 while executing cmake -G "MinGW
> Makefiles"
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake"
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/package/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0"
> -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "/home/user/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/*/*/build/fa16798f9daa5b15fd5cb2fcd5a5d39b602801a0/src/.."

Answer (score 6):

**conan is in a transition state between v1 & v2, so here are 3 solutions, each of them working for conan v1 & v2 recipes:**

### Force Ninja generator globally:

In `<user_home>/.conan`:

- In `conan.conf`:

```ini
[general]
cmake_generator = Ninja
```

- Create the file `global.conf` if it does not exist yet, and add:

```ini
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja
```

### Force Ninja from profile:

In your profile (in `<user_home>/.conan/profiles` folder usually), add:

```ini
[env]
CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja # for conan v1 recipes
[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja # for conan v2 recipes
```

### Force Ninja on demand in conan commands:

```
conan install <path/to/conanfile> -e CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja -c tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja
```

Comment: I had `cmake_generator = Ninja` in `~/.conan/conan.conf` under `[general]` already, but the next line did the trick: once I created `global.conf` as you advised, it detected Ninja!

This was brilliant, thank you so very much!!

Comment: Yes, conan v1 `CMake` build helper listens `cmake_generator` from `conan.conf` or `CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR` env var, and conan v2 `CMakeToolchain` generator listens `tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator`. So if you have both, you're good regardless of what is used under the hood in conan recipes.